# Using redux in complex SPA app

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'am ambiguous about how to implement Redux in a complex app using Atomic Design.

As a remember, Atomic Design is a methodology composed of five distinct stages working together to create interface design. This five stages are :

- **Atoms** like a button, an text input,
- **Molecules** like a search field composed of one input and one button,
- **Organisms** like a search form,
- **Templates** like a generic template,
- **Page** like a search page using a generic template, some search organisms, molecules or atoms like a search form, an item list, an header and a footer.

Imagine an app composed like this :

```
App (page)
    Header (organism IN the template)
        Menu (molecule)
            Button (atom)
            ...
            Button (atom)
        Link (atom)
    Content (div)
        Form (organism IN the page)
            Field (molecule)
                Label (atom)
                Input (atom)
            Field (molecule)
                Label (atom)
                Input (atom)
            Button (atom)
    Footer (organism IN the template)
        Link (atom)
```

On which stage, implement redux ?

- A reducer/container in each organism, an action by button ?
- A reducer/container in the template (for common components), an action by button ?
- Another strategy ?

Answer (score 3):

We have a similar case at work:

- Template & Layout component (`Organic`)
- Specific pages (`Page`)
- Business component (`Organisms` : specific business component for specific page)
- Technical components (`Molecules` & `Atoms`)

Redux main use case is to be able to share common data through multiple components & pages. In many cases, it is application data that are shared: connected user data, identifiers, list of comments, list of bank account, whatever... As a result, a page and functional component must be filled with Redux state data. It means that they receive data from Redux state and passes these data as props to sub-component.

Using an "Atomic Design", it means that only `Page` and `Organisms` are [connected](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) to Redux State.

In our case at work:

- "Specific pages" and "Business component" are connected to Redux.
- "Technical components" only use their own React state. It is better to have technical component handling their own state because it ease the integration in external projects. Having a component that uses Redux means a project needs to add the requires reducers to use the component.
- "Template & Layout component" doesn't use a state and only depends on props.